# trigger mapDispatchToProps but it does not change props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

In my thought, If I create `Z function` in `mapDispatchToProps` by using `dispatch`
    then, I can use `Z function` as `this.props.Z function`. Is it right?

**MainPage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux'  

import store from '../../store'
import * as AlarmContentActions from '../../store/modules/AlarmContent'

class MainPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

    showProps = () => {
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    render() {
        console.log(AlarmContentActions.increment())
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <>
                <button onClick={this.showProps}>here it is</button>
            </>
        )
    }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    increment: () => {
        dispatch(AlarmContentActions.increment())
    }
  })


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage)

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <MainPage />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('main-page'))
```

**AlarmContent.js** **(Ducks Structure include redux-actions & reducers)**

```
import {createAction, handleActions} from 'redux-actions'


const initialState = {
      num: 0
}

//define action types
const INCREMENT = 'AlarmContent/INCREMENT';

//CREATE action
export const increment = createAction(INCREMENT);

//CREATE reducers
export default handleActions({

    [INCREMENT] : (state, action) => {
        return {
            num : state.num + 1
        } 
     }
}, initialState)
```

I made the function `increment()` which dispatches the action type `AlarmContentActions.increment()` at **MainPage.js** but, props is null

[image]
[image]

However, when I dispatch action type which is `AlarmContentActions.increment()` forcibly by `redux-dev-tool', All procedures goes well

[image]

1. I think doing dispatch by `redux-dev-tool` well means that I make `redux store (action, reducers)` well, right?
2. I think I make `mapDispatchToProps` correctly, right?

Then, what's wrong with me?

Comment: @Shubham Khatri I think `export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MainPage)` is connected component isn't it?

Comment: It is connected but isn't used in `ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <MainPage />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('main-page'))`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri really thanks!! it works well!!